# Convert string to Datetime c#

Tags: c#, .net

I get two string.
string a and string b.

```
string a="\n 17 Oct \n \n 2013";

string b=//I get UTC time in string format
```

I need to convert this to "2013-10-17 00-00-00.000" in datetime format. How do I achive this?

Comment: is it a json return from any service or method??

Comment: Are those supposed to be newline characters with backslashes?  And please show exactly what you have for string b.  Have you *tried* anything?

Answer (score 3):

I think the first example makes no problem when you remove the /n from the string

```
string a = "\n 17 Oct \n \n 2013";
string b = a.Replace("\n", "");

DateTime D = DateTime.Parse(b);
```

I am not sure if I used the correct string for the second one. This one comes from the world clock website http://www.worldtimeserver.com/current_time_in_UTC.aspx

```
string utc = " 4:37 AM \n Thursday, October 17, 2013";
string b1 = utc.Replace("\n", "");

DateTime DateUtc = DateTime.Parse(b1);
```

Both seem to get parsed as expected.

Answer (score 2):

The cleanest way is probably to use DateTime.TryParse() with a custom IFormatProvider, or you can use DateTime.TryParseExact().

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9h21f14e.aspx

Comment: More likely, `DateTime.TryParseExact`